# Understand ITIL V3 Function

Tags: itil

I'm studying ITIL V3 and trying to understand the concept of some FUNCTIONS in real world. Let's see:

This concepts are my understand:

1. **Service Desk:** this is like CALL CENTER, where a group of people help users to solve some problems.
2. **Technical Management:** this is like a group of EXPERT PEOPLE that plan what tools and resources use in IT.
3. **Application Management:** This is like managers that monitor all process. (i didn't understand very well what is it)
4. **IT Operations Management:** this is the group of people that will solve some problem in OPERATION, i.e: change a CABLE CAT5 to CAT6, upgrade a user computer with more MEMORY or HD.

So, i would like to know if my idea is correct or incomplete or wrong.

Comment: See [In which Stack Exchange site can one ask questions about ITIL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129355/in-which-stack-exchange-site-can-one-ask-questions-about-itil)

Answer (score 1):

1) **Service Desk:** No, the call center is different from a service desk. Call center and service desk are just some of the options for customer support. Although they are somewhat similar, call centers have more general duties and usually deal with people outside an organization while a service desk usually works internally. But yeah, the part where they are a group of people help users to solve some problems is correct.

2) **Technical Management:** Yes, that is correct. It is the term used for the group of people and the tools and resources they used to carry out one or more processes or activities.

3) **Application management:**  Not particularly focused on managers, but these are a group of people or tools that manage all the applications throughout the life cycle. Be it from design to transition phase, and to operate.

4) **IT Operations Management:** You're right. This is a group of people that is responsible for operation specifically on maintenance and management of an IT infrastructure to ensure that everything within the organization will keep going.

Answer (score 0):

So:

1) Service Desk: 
First and second level of customers assistance. Yes, It's like a call center with a lot of knowledge on common problems.

2) Technical Management: 
They work for the infrastructure, planning server migration, server upgrade, server farm organization and so on

3) Application Management: 
They monitor and resolve application problems. They control stuff like: application exception, slow performance, anomalies in traffic or in available resources

4) IT Operations Management: they work with the building blocks of an infrastructure, like cables, power and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest Form of definitions are as follows: I will share the reference link as well

**Service desk**
This is a function who will be the first point or single point of contact for end user issues.

**Application management**
This is a function who will manage the application development and maintenance issues.

**Technical management**
This is a function who will manage the technical expertise for the ITSM processes and operations.

**Operations management**
This is a function who will manage the day to day operations with respect to IT operations control and IT facilities management.

Link: https://www.itil-docs.com/itil-processes-functions/